# PassportJS y Succes Redirect

Tags: nodejs, express, passport

Necesito poder redirigir a mi usuario a una página u otra según se logue. Está realizado con Passport y tira de la siguiente funición

`router.post('/login', passport.authenticate("local", { successRedirect: "/", failureRedirect: "/login", failureFlash: true, passReqToCallback: true, badRequestMessage: 'Rellena todos los campos' }))`
la key succesRedirect es la que manda cuando se logean. He intentado meter en un if {} trayendo req.body.role === 'USER". Pero sin suerte.
Alguna ayuda?

gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suponiendo que la variable req.body.role es la que decide a donde te diriges podrías usar un if antes de passport.authenticate para definir la dirección destino

```
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  let success;

  if (req.body.role === "USER"){
     success = "/";
  } else {
    success = "/admin";
  }

  passport.authenticate("local", {
    successRedirect: success,
    failureRedirect: "/login",
    failureFlash: true,
    passReqToCallback: true, 
    badRequestMessage: 'Rellena todos los campos'
  })(req, res, next);
});
```